# How to pass a property by reference for update?

Tags: typescript

Passing a object's property by name for reading can be done in a [variety of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833105/in-typescript-how-do-you-specify-the-type-of-properties-of-a-generic-type). However, none of them seems to allow updating the property without explicit type conversions.

The function should be able to get and set the value of the property type-safe. The original use case was to edit the value; for simplicity, let's assume we just want to append a space.

All of these behave the same (get OK, set ERR):

- `{ [k in K]: string }` and `keyof T`

  ```
  function appendSpace1<
      T extends { [k in K]: string },
      K extends keyof T
  >(obj: T, path: K) {
    let x = obj[path]; // `x` is `T[K]`
    let y = x + " ";   // `y` is `string`
    obj[path] = y;     // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.(2322)
    return x;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oKZgCYGVXIQYBMAPACqIYAeUW2AzogEoYRwBO2pA0gDSIGUDjDABzAHwCeVWvSYBrDAE84wROQkAKOACMAVgC4NAglAAWxngEpEAbwBQiRABsMURNUQBeRHv0A2mbmALoA3E6u7ojKPp6IANSIAEQpEc7+QcgWIXHKYYgA9IUaypiIAORCIuIViDBMYHAeyAwMMGJgyLpuiFBwfWUYleQBPCEVAHRaxADMxMTWkRzuIBxI1BEAvg5AA)
- `Record<K, string>` and `string`

  ```
  function appendSpace2<
      T extends Record<K, string>,
      K extends string
  >(obj: T, path: K) {
    let x = obj[path]; // `x` is `T[K]`
    let y = x + " ";   // `y` is `string`
    obj[path] = y;     // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.(2322)
    return x;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oKZgCYGVXIQYCMAPACqIYAeUW2AzogEoYRwBO2pA0gDSIGUDjDABzAHwCeVWvSZCR4iQAo4AIwBWALkTkBBKAAtdPAJSIA3gChEiADYYoiaogC8iDZoDahowF0AblsHJ0QAT3cXRABqRAAiBOC7L19kY38o8MDEAHpcvXDMRAByRVExEsQYJjA4Z2QGBhgxMGR1R0QoOC6ijFLybx5-EoA6FQAmAGYJibMQjicQDiRqYIBfIA)
- `Record<K, string` and `KeysWithValsOfType<T, V>`

  ```
  type KeysWithValsOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: P;
  };

  function appendSpace3<
      T extends { [k in K]: string },
      K extends KeysWithValsOfType<T, string>
  >(obj: T, path: K) {
    let x = obj[path]; // `x` is `T[K]`
    let y = x + " ";   // `y` is `string`
    obj[path] = y;     // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.(2322)
    return x;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDqBLYALAagQwDYIHkAzAFXAgB4SAaKTAPigF4oBreAeyKgG8AoKFADaABSgoAdm07cSUbAiglRAXSgQAHsAgSAJosxQA-FDEAuKBIgA3CACcVFkQG4+AX1d8iAVwkBjYBQOKWwwSD0AZTBsPwgAZgoBQSV1LR19XmFWcSkYRygEYDtJAHMoN2okwRhU7T1FOERUDBx8YjJIKlpC4okS+j56AAoOACMAKwsaKGiMCxgASl4k3AhgKA1mKDHxoVn0FWcoAHpjqAADDXPxRXPlPPOVtagQLc2AaigAIm+jwVOLiBrihbj1So9BDs9tgMGoWCA-skAR1oAByMF9VE3SwcdYKBAoEoSbCjVZQYAccnkKCo+4qVEAOiGACY4szmQsknY1t47FINK43HwgA)

These work (get and set OK), but…

- Using a class

  [This works when using a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58209527/2445204), but it fails when transforming the code into [type with generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCAbAhgZ1VAvFA3gKCimQC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG4CobTLaGpnCBjU1MHoBLMgHNueAL548AMwplewYQHsyUUb3oQqEMsAA8AFQB8AClU0AVqWMAaFoSgBrCCFL5nzgNoBpTQ03EFU5KGMAXQBaAH52ajp6KAgAD2B9ABMMY38IqBioAPYIADcGJygpH2DQ8IiWAEpcCqtravcIgGpOxigAej6oOWRhRBYZPF51QSh0wVI4JDQMbBwSKAAGe1ZSAEZt-igAImAAd1UjqWY8LR09A3M54G2j5COG5lvdfWBHiEEXjR3p8lHcfn8AcdeMD+oNhqMbqDvg8ni8MjCBkMRmMgA):

  ```
  type MyClass = {
    a: number;
    b: number ;
    c: string ;
  }

  function increment<T>(obj: T,
       key: {
        [K in keyof T]-?: number extends T[K] ? K : never
      }[keyof T]
    ) {
      obj[key]++; // fail
    }

  const test: MyClass = {a: 0, b: 1, c: "two"};

  increment(test, "a");
  increment(test, "b");
  increment(test, "c"); // fail
  increment(test, "d"); // fail
  ```
- Constant name

  ```
  function appendSpace4<
      T extends { x: string },
      K extends "x"
  >(obj: T, path: K) {
    let x = obj[path]; // `x` is `T[K]`
    let y = x + " ";   // `y` is `string`
    obj[path] = y;     // OK!
    return x;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwA6oKZgCYGVXIQYAsAPAFCJWIAqiGAHlFtgM6IDeiDAXIq1ABOMMAHNEAXwA0lagGl6TFuwBEDFeQB8ACjgAjAFZ8aUxASgALPnICUnWQBsMUbogC8ifQYDa5iwF0AbkQAehDEAAMGCMQYdgiabzl-CMdnRABPd1cAakQVfOCqMMiMmLjIgWExVKovX2RLf2yMouoSmgzMRAByKpFRHtj2MDgXZFZWGFEwZD0nRCg4Ra6MXsTknoA6bQAmAGZd3ZtZQWcQQSQGQPIJciA)

  … but it is not parameterizable. As soon as one of the `x`es is changed (first to `[k in K]` or second to `keyof T`), `obj[path] = y` turns back into ts2322.

I seem to be able to circle the solution very closely, but just not getting to it. Why is the *set* operation so different?